# WPF - Complex TextBlock layout

Tags: wpf, layout, textblock, sizing

For the past few days I've been trying to wrap my head around the following layout of TextBlocks:

```
-------------------- -----------
|         1        | |         |
-------------------- |    3    |
|       2       |    |         |
-----------------    -----------
```

All of the TextBlocks have dynamic width. They have fixed height and are in a fixed-size container. They need to meet the following requirements:

- 2 has maximum priority - it needs to always be at full length.
- 3 can fill the remaining space left after sizing 2.

When ignoring TextBlock 1, these two requirements could be fulfilled by putting the two other TextBlocks in a Grid, with columns set to "auto" and "*" respectively.

There is a third requirement though:

- 1 assumes all the space it can, but without restricting 3.

Examples:

Long content in block 3 (block 2 content is full length, block 3 content gets trimmed):

```
----------------- -------------
|       1       | |           |
----------------- |     3     |
|       2       | |           |
----------------- -------------
```

Short content in block 3 (both block 2 and 3 content are full length; block 1 fills the remaining space):

```
--------------------- ---------
|         1         | |       |
--------------------- |   3   |
|       2       |     |       |
-----------------     ---------
```

Is there a way to achieve this layout in WPF? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with pure XAML. One way to accomplish your requirements is implementing your own panel that does all the magic. Here is one implementation:

```
public class SpecialPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride (Size constraint)
    {
        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure (constraint);
        }

        return constraint;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride (Size arrangeSize)
    {
        if (VisualChildrenCount != 3)
        {
            return (arrangeSize);
        }

        Size sizeLabel0 = InternalChildren[0].DesiredSize;
        Size sizeLabel1 = InternalChildren[1].DesiredSize;
        Size sizeLabel2 = InternalChildren[2].DesiredSize;

        InternalChildren[1].Arrange (new Rect (0, sizeLabel0.Height, sizeLabel1.Width, sizeLabel1.Height));
        var maxRemainingWidthFor2 = arrangeSize.Width - sizeLabel1.Width;

        if (maxRemainingWidthFor2 <= 0)
        {
            InternalChildren[0].Arrange (new Rect (0, 0, sizeLabel0.Width, sizeLabel0.Height));
        }
        else
        {
            if (maxRemainingWidthFor2 < sizeLabel2.Width)
            {
                InternalChildren[2].Arrange (new Rect (arrangeSize.Width - maxRemainingWidthFor2, 0, maxRemainingWidthFor2, sizeLabel2.Height));
                InternalChildren[0].Arrange (new Rect (0, 0, Math.Min (sizeLabel0.Width, sizeLabel1.Width), sizeLabel0.Height));
            }
            else
            {
                var max0 = arrangeSize.Width - maxRemainingWidthFor2;
                var width0 = Math.Min (sizeLabel0.Width, max0);

                InternalChildren[2].Arrange (new Rect (arrangeSize.Width - sizeLabel2.Width, 0, sizeLabel2.Width, sizeLabel2.Height));
                InternalChildren[0].Arrange (new Rect (0, 0, arrangeSize.Width - sizeLabel2.Width, sizeLabel0.Height));. 
            }
        }

        return arrangeSize;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    <local:SpecialPanel>
        <Label
            x:Name="Label1"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Content="TextBlock00000000000000" />
        <Label
            x:Name="Label2"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Content="TextBloc111111111111" />
        <Label
            x:Name="Label3"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Content="Label333333" />
    </local:SpecialPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it does not work as expected for the second example. I have modified your code to make it work, the last `else` branch needs to be changed to this: `InternalChildren[2].Arrange (new Rect (arrangeSize.Width - sizeLabel2.Width, 0, sizeLabel2.Width, sizeLabel2.Height)); InternalChildren[0].Arrange (new Rect (0, 0, arrangeSize.Width - sizeLabel2.Width, sizeLabel0.Height));`. If you modify your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I'm glad that you got the idea and are able to adapt the logic to your needs. I updated my answer.